# How do I get my Flutter app from Android Studios to xcode?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-android

I have programmed an app that is already uploaded to the Playstore, now I want to do the same in the Appstore.

Unfortunately, I don’t have a Macbook and have to do this via a friend who has xcode on a Mac.

Which flutter file do I have to send to my mate with Mac to open my app programmed in Android Studios (on a Windows computer) in xcode and upload it to the Appstore?

I would really appreciate help from someone :)

Answer (score 0):

- You can share the `ios` directory inside your flutter project to publish the application on App Store.

Comment: Do you mean the IOS folder? Or where can I find it?

Comment: Yes, correct, share that folder!

Comment: How do I send this folder to my friend? You can't send entire folders by mail.

Comment: Create repository on GitHub (github.com)/ Gitlab (gitlab.com)/ BitBucket (bitbucket.org) and share to the user.